# C# WPF - Have a list of containers and wish to update the templates of each container so that the image within changes sizes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am having issues with updating my DataTemplate for the list of "Movie" objects. Specifically I have an image within those objects which is being displayed in a looping list. The object in the center will have a larger image while the images further away will get smaller.

I am using C# and WPF.

In my Window.Resources:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:Movie}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0" Background="Transparent" Width="Auto" Name="MovieDataStack">
        <Image Name="MovieImage" Margin="10,0,10,0" Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Width="{Binding Size}" Height="Auto"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

My Movie class contains a variable called Size which can be changed, but whenever I update the variable the template does not update.

I create a list of movies at the beginning of my program (in App.xaml.cs) and use the list in another xaml (TicketScreen.xaml) file:

```
<dw:LoopingListBox x:Name="movieScroller" Margin="81.683,65.013,66.149,43.342"
                           ItemsSource="{StaticResource Movies}"
                           ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MovieContainerStyle}" Background="Transparent" MouseUp="movieScroller_MouseUp"/>
```

How do I update the images of each child in the looping list? I have a feeling the DataTemplate is used for all the movies, so I can't specify a different size for each movie.

Thanks so much for the help ^^

Comment: Does your Movie object implement INotifyPropertyChanged? You'll have to notify the view that the size property has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Is this MVVM ?

You should have a collection of Data called Movie

A collection of Movie called Movies.

Search threw your collection of Movies and change the property that corresponds to the Item number.

```
int TempIndex;
TempIndex = Movies.Count / 2;
TempMovie = Movies[TempIndex];
TempMovie.Width = 155;
TempMovie.Height = 155;
```

Theres probably a better way to do it, but this is how I've done it in the past. The syntax probably isnt perfect either